# Expanding Search textfield, but then buttons don't work on first click

Tags: jquery, textbox, uisearchbar

Okay so I got one of these fancy search boxes to expand (ie:apple.com) My issue is that what if the users decides they didn't to search after all and decides to click the nav instead it takes 2 clicks, one to blur out of the text field and then once again to click through.

I do not want that 2nd click, my thought is jquery creating a function like:

```
$('.menu a').mouseover(function() {
     $('mysearch').blur();
    });
```

but I feel that this is wrong so is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Could you re-phrase it?

Comment: Is there any realtion between title and description ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/knottAverage/XcDkB/1/

Hope this helps, just using the bare essentials my menu has a drop down.

Click into the text field then try to click on a menu link. It does not link on first click on my web site. I have to click out of the text field first then click on nav with my website. (Note this js fiddle example sometimes works if still in text field)

Answer (score 0):

(Update) After looking more into it and finding this on css tricks helped me see what was going on: http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/123-if-it-moves-when-you-click-make-something-stick/

Turns out once I slowed down the speed from 'fast' to 'slow' it cleared up the issue:

```
$('#search-txt').focus(function () {
     $('.menu a').animate({
         'padding-right': 23,
         'padding-left': 23,
     }, 'slow');
     $(this).animate({
         width: 300
     }, 'fast');
     $('#nav-search').animate({
         width: 408
     }, 'slow');
     }).blur(function () {
          $(this).animate({
          width: 200
     }, 'slow');
     $('#nav-search').animate({
          width: 335
     }, 'slow');
     $('.menu a').animate({
         'padding-right': 30,
         'padding-left': 30,
     }, 'slow');
});
```